# Uso del pronombre "se" en "Se viene la Copa América"

Tags: gramática, modismos, pronombres, chile

Desde hace algunos años se ha vuelto muy frecuente en Chile la expresión **"se viene..."**, con el significado de "ya viene" o "se acerca", sobre todo en publicidad y en el periodismo deportivo. Por ejemplo

> Ya se viene la Copa América.
>
> Este fin de semana se viene una lluvia de ofertas...

Tengo dos preguntas: ¿es un chilenismo o se usa también en otros países?, y ¿es gramaticalmente correcto usar el pronombre "se" en estos casos?

A mí personalmente me disgusta un poco al oído, pero no he podido verificar que esté bien o mal dicho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ¿Es un chilenismo o se usa también en otros países?

Tienen un fuerte uso popular en Argentina y Uruguay, y es utilizada también en Perú, México, Chile, etc. Esto indica que no es un chilenismo, sino una expresión que ha sido aceptada en el habla del pueblo latinomericano y utilizada principalmente cuando se quiere causar sensación, advertir o llamar la atención. Incluso artistas han ocupado este término tan popular, como el argentino Bersuit Vergarabat en su tema de 1998 llamado [*Se Viene*](http://www.lanacion.com.ar/489288-tema-premonitorio).

> ¿Es gramaticalmente correcto usar el pronombre "se" en estos casos?

Depende de dónde estés hablando. *Donde fueres haz lo que vieres*, dice el refrán. Para algunos, 'se viene...' podría ser nada más que un vulgarismo o un error gramatical. En España podrás comprobar que no es una expresión usada popularmente, y podría calificarse como incorrecta. En Hispanoamérica es aceptada, y por ende, no incorrecta para la mayoría. Podrás encontrar una infinidad de fuentes en Hispanoamérica en donde se utiliza la forma 'se viene...' pero no te será facil encontrarlas en España. Esto, *per se*, es un indicativo de que sea una expresión correcta o no, dependiendo del grupo cultural y el contexto en el que te encuentres. Podría decirse que por su uso se la termina aceptando.

En Hispanoamérica, al revisar el contexto en el que se utiliza la expresión 'se viene...', se detecta que la intencionalidad está fuertemente ligada a un proceso que finalmente 'se deja o dejará caer o estallará' como una cosa/evento/circunstancia (que se acerca, que se aproxima). Esto guarda cierta relación, pero no con la misma utilidad y finalidad, con la dada en la fermentación de alimentos como la masa del pan o el vino, o incluso en el ámbito sexual/fisiológico, como se la entiende en España (dependiendo del contexto) cuando se dice 'se vino' o 'se viene'.

Podrás verificar que la utilidad está comúnmente ligada a cosas/eventos/circunstancias que 'se dejarán caer' en las siguientes fuentes mediáticas (algunas de ellas son periódicos tradicionales):

> [Argentina 1](http://www.clarin.com/deportes/tenis/Djokovic-Cilic-puede-venirse-explosiva_0_1340866104.html), [Argentina 2](http://www.urgente24.com/225988-tormenta-en-el-bayern-y-se-viene-la-especialidad-espanola-la-contra), [Argentina](http://www.laqueseviene.com.ar/), [Uruguay 1](http://www.pantallazo.com.uy/auc.aspx?270143,756,0,,0), [Uruguay 2](http://www.elobservador.com.uy/noticia/304952/se-viene-rugby-de-lujo-en-el-charrua/), [Perú](http://www.elcomercio.pe/mundo/latinoamerica/venezuela-cabello-dice-que-se-viene-ataque-militar-eeuu-noticia-1796426), [Chile](http://mtonline.cl/2015/04/se-viene-monomarca-de-motos-para-mujeres-en-chile/), [Colombia](http://www.reconciliacioncolombia.com/historias/detalle/775/se-viene-el-festival-de-cine-de-los-derechos-humanos), [Rusia](http://actualidad.rt.com/opinion/salbuchi/view/47782-Latinoam%C3%A9rica-se-viene-una-%E2%80%9Cprimavera-arabe%E2%80%9D-para-aca). En este último caso se podría decir que hay gran probabilidad de que el artículo para *Russia Today* haya sido escrito por un/una americano/a.

Pero no así [España](http://www.nationalgeographic.es/noticias/ciencia/espacio/gran-tormenta-solar), en donde, por ejemplo, *National Geographic* prefiere el uso de 'una tormenta llega a...' y no de 'se viene una tormenta'.

> Podemos concluir que la forma **'se viene...'** será correcta en el ámbito americano pero no en toda Iberoamérica. Por ende, no es seguro/recomendable utilizarla sabiendo que nos dirigimos, de manera universal, a la audiencia hispanoparlante. Aquí habría que preferir expresiones tales como 'se acerca...', 'viene...' o 'llega...'.

Comment: Qué bien documentado, muchas gracias. Marqué tu respuesta como la aceptada, aunque también me parece interesante el aporte de guifa y Oshnaj de que hay una marca de intensificación o énfasis en ese pronombre "se" agregado.

Answer (score 4):

No es un chilenismo, pero sí es usado en Chile de manera frecuente también para referirnos a las personas que no tuteamos:

> **Se** va a caer. (Cuando no tuteamos.)

O bien:

> **Te** vas a caer. (En donde **"se"** va suprimido y reemplazado por **"te"** porque podemos tutear al individuo.)

Ahora bien, **"se"** es muy usado para hacer referencia a una cosa o persona.

> **Se** lastimó. (Referencia a la persona.)

O bien:

> **Se** quebró. (Referencia a un objeto.)

Por tanto, el uso del **"se"** en escribir o decir **"se viene la Copa América"**, tiene como función referirse a la Copa América (enfatizando lo que viene), pero **viene la Copa América** posee la misma entrega de información.

Incluso acá en Chile es muy común escuchar:

> **Se nos** viene la Copa América.

En donde **"se"** enfatiza demasiado lo que se viene, en este caso, la Copa América.

Comment: tambien en mexico se usa asi.

Answer (score 3):

En principio, a mí no me suena raro, y sin duda no es un mero chilenismo.  Al buscar cosas como «me vengo al» o «nos venimos a la» en Google,<sup>1</sup> es evidente que tras el mundo hispanohablante, abundan (bueno, existen) ejemplos del uso pronominal de *venir*, sobre todo en Cataluña (pero allí, por influencia del catalán, se usa *venir* mucho para significar *ir*).  En los demás casos, tiene un significado de *llegar*.

La RAE recoge dos acepciones pronominales en su *Diccionario* para *venir*:

> **venir**
>   **5.** *intr.* Dicho de una persona: Llegar a conformarse, transigir o avenirse. *U. t. c. prnl.*
>   **27.** *prnl.* Dicho de algunas cosas: Perfeccionarse o constituirse en el estado que deben tener por medio de la fermentación. *Venirse el pan. Venirse el vino.*

Creo que la vigesimaséptima puede demostrar bien lo que se indica en la quinta (y otras, aunque esas no estén marcadas con uso pronominal). No es meramente llegar al estado final, sino que connota un poco el logro que era llegar.  Quizás intente yo enlazar esas demasiado (estoy en pleno modo poético hoy), pero en fin, creo que el significado es no solo *llegar* (que sería *venir* por sí solo), mas *llegar tras dificultad* o *llegar en perfección*.  No parece tan raro ello al considerar el efecto intensificador que pueden tener los pronombres reflexivos, como en el caso de *comerse (algo)*.

---

<sup>1.  El artículo es importante para evitar casos de promoción de pronombres átonos de otros verbos, como sería en el caso de *Me vengo a bañar* (el *me* en este caso es propio del verbo *bañar* y no *venir*, pues es equivalente de *vengo con el propósito de bañarme*).</sup>

Comment: Sí, de hecho en Cataluña se dice "ahora vengo" para decir "ahora voy". Y si está algo despistado, el catalán dirá en castellano "ara vengo" (pues "ahora" se dice "ara").

Answer (score 2):

Creo que no es un chilenismo. Se puede encontrar en distintos medios de distintos países ["se viene notando"](http://www.emprendedores.es/gestion/noticias/marta-izquierdo-ig-markets) o ["Esto **se viene diciendo** desde hace varios años"](http://www.linguee.es/espanol-ingles/traduccion/se+viene+diciendo.html) o ["Esto se ha hecho así porque es como **se viene haciendo** ya desde hace unos años"](http://www.linguee.es/espanol-ingles/traduccion/se+viene+haciendo.html).

Ese uso de "Se viene la Copa América" me parece que es como un intento de uso del "se" impersonal, pero creo que suena mal precisamente porque es innecesario o forzado el uso de una oración impersonal en ese caso.

> *Llega la Copa América*. (O *Viene la Copa América*.)

Tienen el mismo significado que "Se viene la Copa América", y no fuerzan el uso impersonal.

Aunque una oración impersonal se construye con el "se" + verbo en tercera persona del singular, este uso no casa con el "se" impersonal. Mientras que "se viene haciendo" o "se viene notando" son oraciones que carecen de sujeto gramatical, "Se viene la Copa América" o "Se viene una lluvia de ofertas" claramente tienen un sujeto gramatical.

Por tanto, creo que ese uso particular es incorrecto, y debería ser:

> Ya viene (o llega) la Copa América.
>
> Este fin de semana viene una lluvia de ofertas.

Comment: OK, me queda claro que fuera de Latinoamérica es inusual y, de hecho, por tu respuesta parece que no lo has escuchado con el significado que le damos acá (que, como Oshnaj y guifa aclaran, es un "se" enfatizador). Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.