# ¿Es lo mismo "por su uso termina aceptándosela" que "por su uso se la termina aceptando"?

Tags: reflexivos, oraciones-impersonales

Haciendo un poco de *copy-editing*, me he encontrado en [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/12785/13628) con la siguiente oración:

> [Una expresión puede ser correcta o no] dependiendo del grupo cultural y el contexto en el que te encuentres. Podría decirse que por su uso **termina aceptándosele**.

Entiendo el significado como que la expresión termina siendo aceptada en las regiones en las que se usa más.

Leísmos aparte, creo que la última parte de la frase es incorrecta tal cual está redactada; pues el "se" pospuesto al verbo se asocia con los verbos reflexivos o pronominales, y tal parece que la frase dijera que alguien termina aceptándose la expresión para sí mismo/a, lo cual no tiene sentido.

Siendo así, la he cambiado por:

> Podría decirse que por su uso se la termina aceptando.

Aunque igual hubiera valido sin el "la" también.

¿Es correcta mi apreciación? ¿Es válido posponer el "se" impersonal al verbo?

Comment: Cuando es solo impersonal el primer verbo (común con verbos de tipo incluir, parecer, etc) llevaba que en tales casos era obligatorio proclisis, y que además era posible hacer enclisis con el otro, pero tendría que revisar con mucho cuidado lo que dice la gramática)

Comment: Bueno dice el DPD que si es impersonal, es obligatorio enclisis pero los ejemplos son de verbos que son por si solos impersonales, sin ser necesario un *se* pasivo.

Comment: Gracias para recordarme. A ver si tengo el tiempo para hacer una respuesta detallada

Answer (score 1):

Según el artículo *[Se venden casas, Se buscan actores frente a Se busca a los culpables](https://www.rae.es/consultas/se-venden-casas-se-buscan-actores-frente-se-busca-los-culpables)* de la RAE (**negritas mías**),

> Si el elemento nominal sobre el que recae la acción verbal expresa cosa, **debe emplearse la construcción de pasiva refleja**; por tanto, el verbo ha de ir en plural si este elemento es plural.

Por tanto, la oración

- Por su uso, se termina aceptando la expresión

es una pasiva refleja, lo que quiere decir que **"*la expresión*" es el sujeto de la oración**. Al ser sujeto, no puede ser sustituido por el pronombre *la*, que solo puede sustituir a complementos directos. Por tanto, la única posibilidad es la elipsis del sujeto, sin sustitución por ningún pronombre:

- [Una expresión puede ser correcta o no] dependiendo del grupo cultural y el contexto en el que te encuentres. Podría decirse que por su uso **[termina aceptándose/se termina aceptando]**.

La oración

- <s>Por su uso, **[termina aceptándoselas/se las termina aceptando]**</s>

es incorrecta según la RAE y mi experiencia. Puede que la diferencia se note aún más en el plural: la opción correcta

- Esas expresiones no eran correctas, pero por su uso **[se terminaron aceptando/terminaron aceptándose]**

me suena (por lo menos a mí) mucho más natural que la incorrecta

- <s>*Esas expresiones no eran correctas, pero por su uso **[se terminó aceptándolas/terminó aceptándoselas]**</s>

Answer (score 0):

Podría ser lo mismo, pero la segunda frase podrá también ser la voz pasiva impersonal porque en ella “se” se antepone.